# Boxplot in Pandas: grouped boxplot with aggregate

Tags: python, dataset

I got a dataset which is about rainfall in the year. Below is an example of the dataset I am working with.

Month  |Precipitation

1  |0.2

1  |     -0.1

1   |     0.3

1    |    0.04

2     |   0.4 

2      | -0.02

...

...

I would like to plot a boxplot (subplot of different months) and a sum of precipitation of each month.

I have tried to create a new dataframe with groupby then boxplot that dataframe, but there is an error, saying 'Series' object has no attribute 'boxplot''

I have tried the following codes and both doesn't seem working

```
df.groupby('Month')['Precipitation'].sum().boxplot
```

AND

```
df2=df.groupby('Month')['Precipitation'].sum()
df2.boxplot()
```

What should I fix in the code for this problem? Thank you!